# Is there a way to determine what type a class is an instance of in Java?

Tags: java, oop, class, inheritance

Say I have 3 classes like so:

```
class A {}
class B extends A {}
class C extends A {}
```

Would it then be possible to determine whether a particular object was an instance of `A`, `B`, or `C`?

I thought that something like this might work:

```
if (myObject.getClass().isInstance(B.class)) {
    // do something for B
} else (myObject.getClass().isInstance(C.class)) {
    // do something for C
} else {
    // do something for A
}
```

but after reading a little I think it would always evaluate as B since it's just testing if a cast would work and there's no substantial differences between them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do this:

```
if (myObject instanceof B) {
    // do something for B
} else (myObject instanceof C) {
    // do something for C
} else {
    // do something for A
}
```

Answer (score 9):

The simpler and faster code is:

```
if (myObject instanceof B) {
} else if (myObject instanceof C) {
} else if (myObject instanceof A) {
}
```

Note that the order is important: you have to have the test for `A` last, as that will succeed for instances of `B` and `C` as well.

However, your original code would nearly work. `Class.isInstance` checks whether the value really is an instance of the given class or any superclass. So if `myObject` is an instance of `C`, then `B.class.isInstance(myObject)` will return false. All you've got wrong is that you're calling `getClass()` on `myObject` unnecessarily, instead of using `B.class` etc.

This is the approach you would take if you didn't know which classes you were interested in at compile time - the `instanceof` operator only works when you can specify the type statically in code.

Now if you want to find out whether `myObject` is an instance of *exactly* `B` (and not a subclass) then just use:

```
if (myObject.getClass() == B.class)
```

(This will blow up if `myObject` is a null reference, of course.)

Comment: Answered in typical stack-overfl...I mean, Skeet-overkill style. :D

Answer (score 1):

You also might want to look at the [double dispatch idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch) which is an OO way of changing behaviour based on the type of an argument in languages which don't support multi-methods.

Answer (score 0):

There is the `instanceof` operator that does what you want, as others have answered.

But beware that if you need something like this, it's a sign that there might be a flaw in the design of your program. The better, more object oriented way to do this is by using polymorphism: put a method in the superclass A, override that method in B and C, and call the method on myObject (which should have type A):

```
A myObject = ...;  // wherever you get this from

// Override someMethod in class B and C to do the things that are
// specific to those classes
myObject.someMethod();
```

`instanceof` is ugly and should be avoided as much as possible, just like casting is ugly, potentially unsafe and should be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

you could do this

```
if (myObject.getClass() == B.class) {
    // do something for B (not subclasses of b!!!)
} else if(myObject.getClass() == C.class) {
    // do something for C (not subclasses of c!!!)
} else if(myobject.getClass() == A.class) {
    // do something for A (not subclasses of A!!)
} else if(myobjects instanceof A){
   //all other subclasses of A
}
```